# Handling NaNs in linear regression -- scipy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, linear-regression

I have a data set with `NaN`s scattered amongst the data. I'm using pandas to extract the data from a file, and numpy to process it. This is my code for reading the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def makeArray(band):
    """
    Takes as argument a string as the name of a wavelength band.
    Converts the list of magnitudes in that band into a numpy array,
    replacing invalid values (where invalid == -999) with NaNs.
    Returns the array.
    """
    array_name = band + '_mag'
    array = np.array(df[array_name])
    array[array==-999]=np.nan
    return array

#   Read data file
fields = ['no', 'NED', 'z', 'obj_type','S_21', 'power', 'SI_flag', 
          'U_mag', 'B_mag', 'V_mag', 'R_mag', 'K_mag', 'W1_mag',
          'W2_mag', 'W3_mag', 'W4_mag', 'L_UV', 'Q', 'flag_uv']

magnitudes = ['U_mag', 'B_mag', 'V_mag', 'R_mag', 'K_mag', 'W1_mag',
          'W2_mag', 'W3_mag', 'W4_mag']

df = pd.read_csv('todo.dat', sep = ' ',
                   names = fields, index_col = False)

#   Define axes for processing
redshifts = np.array(df['z'])
y = np.log(makeArray('K'))
mask = np.isnan(y)
```

I guess a minimal working example would be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

randomNumberGenerator = np.random.RandomState(1000)
x = 4 * randomNumberGenerator.rand(100)
y = 4 * x - 1+ randomNumberGenerator.randn(100)
y[50] = np.nan

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
fit = slope*x + intercept

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, fit)
plt.show()
```

Commenting out the `y[50] = np.nan` line in the MWE produces a nice graph, but including it produces the same error message as with my actual data:

```
C:\Users\Jeremy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
C:\Users\Jeremy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
C:\Users\Jeremy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1818: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  cond2 = cond0 & (x <= self.a)
```

A snippet of the actual dataframe:

```
no  NED z   obj_type    S_21    power   SI_flag U_mag   B_mag   V_mag   R_mag   K_mag   W1_mag  W2_mag  W3_mag  W4_mag  L_UV    Q   flag_uv
1   SDSSJ000005.95+145310.1 2.499   *   0.0 0.0     -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  0.0 0.0 NONE
4   SDSSJ000009.27+020621.9 1.432   UvS 0.0 0.0     -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  0.0 0.0 NONE
5   SDSSJ000009.38+135618.4 2.239   QSO 0.0 0.0     -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  0.0 0.0 NONE
6   SDSSJ000011.37+150335.7 2.18    *   0.0 0.0     -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  0.0 0.0 NONE
11  SDSSJ000030.64-064100.0 2.606   QSO 0.0 0.0     -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  15.46   -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  23.342  56.211000000000006  UV
15  SDSSJ000033.05+114049.6 0.73    UvS 0.0 0.0     -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  0.0 0.0 NONE
27  LBQS2358+0038   0.95    QSO 0.0 0.0     17.342  18.483  18.203  17.825  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  -999.0  23.301  56.571999999999996  UV
```

I'm plotting each of the `_mag` columns against `z`, and I'm trying to compute and plot a linear regression, excluding the `NaN`s.

I've tried `numpy.linalg`, `numpy.poly`, `scipy.stats.linregress`, and `statsmodels.api`, but it doesn't seem like any of them can easily handle the `NaN`s. The other questions I've found on SE are leading me around in circles.

How can I plot the OLS regression fit over the top of my data, like the MWE shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your data to a data frame in order to remove the whole column which contains at least one NAN value. Then, you won't get the warning as received earlier. Try this,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd

randomNumberGenerator = np.random.RandomState(1000)
x = 4 * randomNumberGenerator.rand(100)
y = 4 * x - 1+ randomNumberGenerator.randn(100)
y[50] = np.nan

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': x})
df1['y'] = y
df1 = df1.dropna()
x = df1.x
y = df1.y

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
fit = slope*x + intercept

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, fit)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `df.dropna()` see the following link : [pandas.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)